# character encoding in xml feed data

Tags: php, xml, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm loading an XML feed from a remote source like this:

```
if ($reader = XMLReader::open($url)) {    
    while ($reader->read()) {
        if ( $reader->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT && $reader->localName == 'MainNode' ) 
        {
            $node   = $reader->expand();
            $dom    = new DomDocument();
            $n      = $dom->importNode($node,true);
            $dom->appendChild($n);
            $xml    = simplexml_import_dom($n);
            echo($xml->Remarks); // problem here
         }
    }
}
```

When I view the page in a browser, it has bad characters in the page like this:

```
â€œcity within a cityâ€
```

If I use Chrome tools and change the page encoding from Western to UTF8, the problem disappears and the characters all look correct: `“city within a city”`

When I directly insert the raw string into my database, which is a UTF8 db, and then display it on a page, which is also encoded as utf8, it shows up like this: `â€œcity within a cityâ€`. If I try using `utf8_encode` on the string, it looks like this: `Ã¢Â€Âœcity within a cityÃ¢Â€Â`. If I use `utf8_decode` it shows `?city within a city?`

How should I handle this?

Comment: Do you have access to change the file's format? I've in the past had problems with the file itself. It appears differently on windows then linux to fix my issue there. I opened the file in notepad then saved as  encoding UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have special ( " )'s why not just [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) those.

```
$output = str_replace('Your Special Quotes', '"', $string);
```

Here is a function for all of Microsoft's funny characters

```
function convert_smart_quotes($string) 
{ 
    $search = array(chr(145), 
                    chr(146), 
                    chr(147), 
                    chr(148), 
                    chr(151)); 

    $replace = array("'", 
                     "'", 
                     '"', 
                     '"', 
                     '-'); 

    return str_replace($search, $replace, $string); 
}
```

Then utf8_decode

You can also try [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Here is also a useful link http://shiflett.org/blog/2005/oct/convert-smart-quotes-with-php

Comment: @Demodave-- as stated above, the actual page the data is being displayed on is being set to UTF8 mode, using the proper content-type meta.

Comment: If any of these items help you fill free comment which one so that I could possibly remove the others.

Comment: @Demodave-- I ended up using a version of the custom function to replace the chars. Thanks for the thought!